# In Express is it a best practice to use `req.session` to transfer data between routes?

Tags: node.js, express

**Environment:** Node.js, Express

**Question:** In Express is it a best practice to use `req.session` to transfer data between routes?

**Background:** I'm using `req.session` to transfer client data between routes and it seems to work fine.  However I don't work on a team and I don't have anyone to check with to see if this a smart way to transfer data between routes.

**Example:** Below is an oversimplified express server that is mock connected to a mongoose server.  In the default `/` route example@example.com is logged in.  In the `edit_user_data` route the name is changed.  This basic pattern of sending user data to routes using req.session works but I'm not sure if this is a good way to approach this problem.

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const app = express();

app.use(session({
    name: process.env.SESSION_NAME,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    cookie: {
        sameSite: true,
        secure: false,
    } 
}));

app.get('/', async function(req, res, next) {

    let emailAddress = example@example.com;
    let userData = await User.findOne({ email: emailAddress });

    req.session.userData = userData;

    res.render('home_page', { userData });
});

app.get('/edit_user_data', async function(req, res, next) {

    let editName = 'Roger';
    await User.updateOne({ email: userData.email }, { name: editName });

    res.render('/edit_user_data');
});

app.listen(8080);
```

Comment: I suppose if those data makes sense to be on session.  You could set the data directly on `request`. For example, setting `user` on `request` (`req.user = aLoggedInUser`) is pretty common.  There are other options, too, like a single-instance service, continuation local storage, persistent storage (redis, mysql, etc.)...  Given the way you're using session--adding data in one route then deleting it in another--I would say there are better options available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In Express is it a best practice to use `req.session` to transfer data between routes?

No, not really.

The session object is for storing state for the user that might need to be regularly accessed on many routes such as their name, their login status, etc...  It is generally not used for temporary state being sent from one route to the next.

If you're trying to set a multiplier in one route and then use that multipler in another route, that is kind of breaking the REST model for self-describing pages that don't depend upon some magic sequence of events happening before this URL is hit.  For example, if the user bookmarks your `/multiplier` route, they may get a different result every time they go there.  This is not really how the session should be used.  It can be used that way, but for the example you show, unless the multiplier value was more like a user preference that is intended to apply to lots of pages and persist for a long time (which it isn't, since you're using it then deleting it), then it doesn't really make sense to put this in the session.  It breaks the REST capabilities of the `/multiplier` URL because it renders something different or an error depending upon what came before it.  That's not the REST concept.

The REST concept would be to put the multiplier in a query parameter for the URL:

```
/multiplier?value=10;
```

Then, whoever is rendering the page can just get that value from the query parameter and the URL is self describing, stands alone, works for a bookmark, works properlly even if there are multiple windows open, has no race conditions and is consistent with the REST design philosophy.

```
app.get('/multiplier', function(req, res, next) {
    let clientData = +(req.query.value || 1);
    let output = clientData * 100;
    res.send(output);
});
```

---

In the new example you added to your question, you first do a:

```
GET /
```

And, that somehow inserts some state into the session that then effects the result of:

```
GET /edit_user_data
```

That just doesn't make any sense to me.  In a REST architecture, a GET should be idempotent.  That means that a given URL for a given GET should generate the same result every time.  Your `GET /edit_user_data` is not that way.   What it does apparently depends upon something that came before so that specific URL can have a different effect each time.  That's NOT idempotent.

You would use a POST to insert a new record in the database or a PUT to modify an existing record in the database and you would send the data with the request, not have previously squirreled it way somewhere into some state.

What you're attempting to do is not a REST architecture.  There are many good tutorials or descriptions of the REST architecture.  I'd suggest you read a few of them.  Here's [one such article](https://restfulapi.net/http-methods/).

Comment: Your insight into the REST model and query parameters was brilliant.  When I run into that type of problem I will use your thoughts!  However my multiplier route was a bad example.  I was simply trying to demonstrate the movement of data between routes.  I am using req.session to hold user data inside a dashboard environment.  The data is sent from the main dashboard route to another route that handles editing name, phone number, email, etc. etc.

Comment: @myNewAccount - If you add another example to your question, I can add comments on that.  It really depends upon what the data is and how it's used on whether it's a good design or not.  All I can do is answer based on specific scenarios.

Comment: I created a slightly better (but also very simplified) example.  It's closer to what I'm doing.  In my real app I use HTML forms and POSTs to collect data as well as a Mongoose server to store the data.  But this sort of shows how `req.session.userData` was sent between routes.

Comment: @myNewAccount - The new example has the same issues - it's not consistent with a REST architecture.  I added comments to the end of my answer to address that new example.

Comment: Very interesting, dang.  But if I'm updating user data like name, phone number, password, etc. wouldn't I want to keep those in the session?  They belong in the URL?

Comment: @myNewAccount - If you're updating a record in a database, you should be using a PUT and the data for the updated record should be sent in the body of the request.  It should be done in one request, not setup in one request and stored in session and then executed in another request.  If you're adding a record to the database, you should be using a POST and the data should be in the body of the request.  A GET should retrieve data, not set data.  This should be a good read for you: [REST Design: PUT vs. POST](https://restfulapi.net/rest-put-vs-post/).

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00 I will read it!  But GET and POST are the only methods available in HTML.

Comment: @myNewAccount - PUT is available via Ajax calls in browser Javascript.  For a pure HTML solution, you can bastardize POST and use it instead of PUT.  Better that instead of using a GET which should be retrieving data, not modifying data.